# Add weight value to selected verts

Tags: rigging

I'd like to add influence for one bone in my rig to multiple verts. By that I mean each of these verts currently have unique vertex weights applied for multiple bones. I'd like to add 0.075 to the weight of Bone.005 to all of the selected verts. The result of this should be that each of the selected verts still have unique weights for all the bones, but they all have had 0.075 added to Bone.005 weights

Hope this makes sense?
If it helps, the way I would do this in Maya would be to select the verts, open the Paint skin Weights tool, Select the joint from the list, change the Paint operation to Add, set the value to 0.075 then click Flood

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter weight paint mode.  Select vertex group "Bone.005".  Switch to vertex masking and select the vertices you want to be affected by the operation (possibly, by tabbing into edit and selecting there where selection tools are better.)  Use a "levels" operation (under "weights" menu if you'd like, but I searchbar it.)  On the operator panel, set the offset to 0.075.  This will add 0.075 to the weights of all selected vertices.

Any weights that are already at 1.0 or close will not get weights larger than 1.0 via this operation; Blender's vertex groups are clamped to the 0,1 range.

Comment: Thanks for this! 
I would never have thought to do that.